# Tilt.js disabling on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to disable tilt.js on moblie. I thoguth that it sholud be simple script that checks what width of screen is. So i made something like that but its not working. My div class is .tilt-el

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 // Destroy tilt
if ($(window).width() < 480) {
  var element = $('.tilt-el');
  element.tilt.destroy.call(element);
}else{
 // Reset tilt
  $('.tilt-el').tilt();
}

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today, and couldn't find anything.

I wrote some code and it seems to work.

```
function destroyTilt() {
    var tiltElements = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-tilt]`);
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1025px)");
    if (mq.matches) {
        for (var i = 0, len = tiltElements.length; i < len; i++) {
            tiltElements[i].vanillaTilt.destroy();
        }
    } else {
        console.log('pedal');
    }
}
destroyTilt();
```

**I'm still learning to code, so I'm sure the code is flawed. If anybody can give me pointers on how to improve it, that'd be great.**

Answer (score 1):

```js
if(screen.width < 900){
    $("[data-tilt]").addClass("hidetilt");
}
```

```css
.hidetilt{
    transform: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My friend width is not a good idea to detect the device. It is better to use UserAgent.

How can you do that? I'll tell you

```js
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  console.log('is mobile')
} else {
  console.log('isnt mobile')
}
```

Hope it helps

Update:

```
var element = $('.tilt-el').tilt();
element.tilt.destroy.call(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, still i cant destroy tilts :( But thank you for that answer

```js
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  console.log('is mobile')
} else {
  console.log('isnt mobile')
}
```